# How to correctly parallelise RSeQC scripts with GNU parallel?

Tags: rna-seq, rna, rna-alignment

I have a `.bam`, as ouput from STAR aligner,  from which I need to extract some info using RSeQC while using all the computational resources available to increase speed. To accomplish that I am using GNU parallel. Currently I am doing it like this:

1. Split the main .bam per chromosome, generating files with the suffix Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.REF

   ```
   bamtools split -in Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam  -reference
   ```
2. Calculate the clipping profile

   ```
   ls Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.REF_* | parallel --joblog clipping_profile.log --eta --bar --max-procs 20 --jobs 20 'clipping_profile.py -i {} -s "SE" -o RSeQC.clipping.profile/clipping_profile.{.}'
   ```

This will generate a `.r`, `.pdf`and a `.xlxs` for each chromosome, thus ending up with a lot of files. I am forced to split the `.bam` per chromosome as I am not able to find a `--recstart` nor a `--recend` in the compressed `.bam`.

### Question

Is there a better way to split a `.bam` file using GNU parallel and RSeQC' programs (*e.g.* `split_bam.py`), such that one gets the outputs from a single input file?

Inspired by ole.tange's [thread](https://www.biostars.org/p/63816/), I have also tried this, though unsuccessfully:

```
cat star_outputAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam | parallel --block 1G -k --joblog splitbam3.log --max-procs 20 --jobs 20 --pipe 'split_bam.py -i {} -r ../../My_genomes/GCA.GRCh38/GRCh38_wgEncodeGencodeAttrsV28_all_rRNA.bed12 -o splitbam3'
```